# Generate a dynamic C# class using Dapper with the Database table having a composite key

Tags: c#, dapper

I have a database table that has a composite key. In my C# code, I don't use Domain classes but based on the name of the table configured in the database, I read that and generate the C# domain class. Has anyone tried to dynamically generate a C# class from the configuration table that has a composite key?

Example:
Let's say I have a `User` table with a composite key, `UserID` and `UserName`. I dynamically generate the `User` class in C# using reflection and Dapper. How can I generate the `User` class dynamically and insert a record into the `User` table which now requires 2 values, `UserID` and `UserName`?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of models with composite keys, I have used the attribute [ExplicitKey] instead of [Key].